# Spark streaming Kafka not working when Kafka and Worker are on different Machines

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a simple Spark streaming app that works with kafka(deploy on my machine, as in the basic config that ships with the distribution). When i run my sparkstreaming app on a standalone server with my master and worker on my machine and therefore the same machine as kafka everything is fine.

However as soon as i decide to add another node/worker, or if i simply only start the worker on my second machine (Where Kafka is not) nothing happen anymore. The Streaming tab disappear. But i don't see any error in the stderr of the driver or the worker in the ui.

With no error i just don't know where to look at. The application just does not work.

If anyone has ever experience something of the sort, please would you share some suggestions?

I use the proper machine ip adress of my local network

Comment: I seem to remember hitting a similar problem, the issue was that the second machine didn't resolve correctly the address of the Kafka node (i.e. Kafka advertised itself with an address which wasn't reachable from the second machine). In order to diagnose it further check the address you are using in Spark and the advertised address configured in the Kafka broker.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to know the one that my broker is defaulting too, like from the command line ?

Comment: from the Kafka documentation (http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html) if not provided uses whatever `java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()` returns. I suggest to specify the property `advertised.host.name` in your broker configuration.

Comment: PS: If you are using Kafka 0.10 note that property is now deprecated and used only if the new (`advertised.listeners`) one is not specified.

Comment: That was it !! Thank you

Comment: You should put it as an official answer :)

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible issue which would cause this behaviour is a misconfiguration of the Kafka advertised host.

By default a Kafka broker advertise itself using whatever `java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()`. The returned address might not be reachable from the node running the Spark worker.

In order to fix the issue you should set the advertised address on each Kafka broker to be reachable from all the nodes.

The relevant Kafka broker configuration options are:

- Kafka 0.9: `advertised.host.name`
- Kafka 0.10: `advertised.listeners` (with fallback on `advertised.host.name`)

For further details on these configuration parameters refer to the Kafka documentation for version [0.9](http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) or [0.10](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs)